# How to cast column name to prevent SQL injection?

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

When defining `EXECUTE` in a PostgreSQL function, I can cast tables names to `::regclass` to make sure they are valid relation names. Now, I want to extend that to column names, but I cannot find the right type for that.

My code:

```
...
BEGIN
    EXECUTE '
    UPDATE ' || tbl::regclass || ' SET ' || col || '=someVal WHERE idcol=id
    ';
END;
...
```

What to put after `col` to cast it to a column name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
quote_ident(col)
```

[String functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html)